# Why do i need 'return -1'?

Tags: return

I am just newbie and I saw this code block with return at last. I just don't know why it has return at last. I know the meaning of return -1 , but I don't know why it needs. Anyone can explain it? Thank you

```
      Function linearSearch(arr, val){
          for (var i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
              if(arr[i]===val){
                  return i;
              }
          }
          return -1;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, developers will create a default value to be returned to signal that no other valid answer is found.

Your function looks through an array (for example, `[4,8,15,16,23,42]`), and a value is given to search for (say `16`).  `linearSearch([4,8,15,16,23,42], 16)` would return the index of where 16 is located, with the first number being index `0`, and so on.  So, it would return that 16 is in index number `3`.

If `val` not contained in the array `arr`, like suppose you ran `linearSearch([4,8,15,16,23,42], 108)`.  The `for` loop would run through, not return an index, and then return `-1` to signal that `val` is not found in `arr`.  This is especially important for typed languages.  This function might be declared to return an integer.  So, it would need to return *something*.  `-1` is a great integer to return to indicate "failure" if "success" is indicated by a positive integer.

You could then do something like

```
idx = linearSearch([4,8,15,16,23,42], 108)
if (idx == -1) {
  console.log("value not found in array")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your awesome answer. Just curious if I just add this code right after if statement ' else{ return -1;' then is it still working? Right now 'return-1' is located outside of for loop.

Comment: @JAEINKIM - if you have an `else { return -1 }` then it would look at the first item in `arr`, and either return `0` if it matched, or `-1` if it didn't.  It would prematurely exit out of the loop without checking the other values in `arr`.  You'll want to keep the `return -1` outside of the loop so you can look through your entire `arr`, and `return -1` only if no matches were found.